# How to get am/pm values from google material time picker in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext, material-components-android, android-timepicker, google-material-icons

```
binding.etFirstTime.setOnClickListener{
            val picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder ()
                .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
                . setHour( 12 )
                .setMinute(10)
                .setTitleText("Select Shop's Timing")
                .build()
            picker.showNow(childFragmentManager,"Time")

            picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener{
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide some context to your question beyond just a block of code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get the time format.
Just use `picker.hour`. It returns the hour of day in the range [0, 23]

Comment: I want to access the am/pm selector, because I want to update my UI screen with the the selected hour, minute and am or pm  in the  text view, when selected by the user.

Comment: We cant access the selected am or pm values from the user?

Comment: @JosusPraiser No, you can't.

Comment: @GabrielMariotti so in a 12 hour format ,if a user selects 9th hour, then how can we change the UI as AM/PM?

Comment: @JosusPraiser No way. You just can have to hour in the range 0-23

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 val selectedTime = Calendar.getInstance()
 selectedTime[0, 0, 0, picker.hour, picker.minute] = 0

 val formattedTime = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault()).format(selectedTime.time)
```

Output example: 09:45:00 PM